# WCF and WebLogic SAML interop

Tags: wcf, weblogic, saml

I have WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.5.0 as web service provider and .Net 4 client.
I have access to server and client sources.
I need to make service requests using SAML tokens to pass credentials and some metadata. I don't need STS provider, client can sign SAML token with his private cert.

Has anybody done that?

Right now I don't care if it is SAML1 or SAML2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the good starting point for you would be to get familiar with Windows Identity Foundation  (WIF), then you can download the WCF samples and one of the sample is of STS where they have shown how to make your own STS if you don't have one. STS in the sample is a service, but you can pretty much reuse the code to make it into a DLL that will have a method like issue, and you can pass the SAML signing cert as parameter to it.

This will return the SAML token and you can then attach the SAML token to the Service call by using:

`ChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(samlToken)`